# JQuery Drag Dock Panel like the silverlight blacklight control tool kit drag dock panel

Tags: jquery, html, silverlight, blacklight

I'm trying to find some examples of how to create drag dock panels like the silverlight blacklight contorls in JQuery. Any links or examples would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check this widget. It is an open source MIT license.

http://www.dockspawn.com/

It does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another framework, and it is a responsive layout. Please check this one [Web Cabin Docker](https://github.com/WebCabin/wcDocker).